# Windows rootfs.size-gb label is not expanding volume to specified size

Tags: containerd

We use to have storage-opts in Docker . Do we have anything similar in containerd to work on

Windows rootfs.size-gb label is not expanding volume to specified size in containerd

We need windows containers with more C: drive currently it defaults to only 20 Gb

Can you please help me with a solution

We use to have storage-opts in Docker . Do we have anything similar in containerd